# Can I optimize distributively multiple models at the same time?

Tags: optuna

I understand that I can do distributed optimization with [Optuna](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/distributed.html). However, I don't know if I can do it with multiple models at the same time?

For example:

```
optuna create-study --study-name "distributed-example1" --storage "sqlite:///example.db"

optuna create-study --study-name "distributed-example2" --storage "sqlite:///example.db"
```

Then in example1.py:

```
import optuna

def objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_uniform('x', -10, 10)
    return (x - 2) ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    study = optuna.load_study(study_name='distributed-example1', storage='sqlite:///example.db')
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
```

Then in example2.py:

```
import optuna

def objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_uniform('x', -10, 10)
    return (x - 2) ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    study = optuna.load_study(study_name='distributed-example2', storage='sqlite:///example.db')
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Optuna supports running multiple studies simultaneously by using the same storage (DB).

Comment: NOTE:  These storage instances cannot be SQLite per Optuna documentation:
https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/004_distributed.html?highlight=distributed
(see both notes at bottom of page, one of which refers to:)
https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5